# If $X \subseteq \Bbb{A}^n$ is a subvariety, then $\mathcal{O}_X(X) = A(X)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think it is standard notation to write $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ for the ring of regular functions $f:X \to k$ that are regular everywhere on $X$, and $A(X)$ for the coordinate ring of $X$, which for convenience is identified here with this subring $\{\frac{[F]}{1} : [F] \in A(X)\}$ of the field of rational functions.

I need help with proving $\mathcal{O}_X(X) = A(X)$. I have the following proof and need an explanation for the assertion indicated below:

For $h \in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$, given any $p \in X$, we can write $h = \frac{[F]}{[G]}$, where $F, G \in k[x_1, \dots , x_n]$, $G(p) \not= 0$. Let $$J = \{G \in k[x_1, \dots , x_n] |h\cdot [G] \in A(x) \}$$

be an ideal in $k[x_1, \dots , x_n]$. It is then written that $I(X)\subseteq J$. I want to know how this is so? The reason given is that because if we have an element of $I(X)$, then the class $h \cdot [G] = 0 \in A(X)$, which is true but it doesn't mean that $I(X) \subset J$.

It then follows that $Z(J) = \phi$ so $1 \in J$ and this means $h= h \cdot 1 \in A(X)$ hence $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \subseteq A(X)$.

Comment: Your "assertion indicated below" is confusing- there are multiple instances of $G$ that seem like they might need to be different. (Is the $G$ in $h=\frac{F}{G}$ the same as the $G$ in $J=\{G\in \cdots\}$?)

I also wonder what definition you're using of coordinate ring - this problem should be an exercise in noting that the two definitions are the same.

Comment: @KReiser This is confusing for me too. $A(X) = k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I(X)$, but I think here it is just identified with $\{\frac{[F]}{1} : [F] \in A(X)\}$, which is a subring the field of rational functions, $[F] \in A(X)$ is the equivalence class of the polynomial $F \in k[x_1 \dots , x_n ].$ The ideal $J$ is just defined like that so we can show later show $Z(J)=\phi$ to get $ 1 \in J$. I think $G$ isn't necessairly meant to be that which is appearing the quotient.